# Recursively retrieving links from web page in Java

Tags: java, http, recursion

I'm working on a simplified website downloader (Programming Assignment) and I have to recursively go through the links in the given url and download the individual pages to my local directory.

I already have a function to retrieve all the hyperlinks(href attributes) from a single page, `Set<String> retrieveLinksOnPage(URL url)`. This function returns a vector of hyperlinks. I have been told to download pages up to level 4. (Level 0 being the Home Page) Therefore I basically want to retrieve all the links in the site but I'm having difficulty coming up with the recursion algorithm. In the end, I intend to call my function like this :

`retrieveAllLinksFromSite("http://www.example.com/ldsjf.html",0)`

```
Set<String> Links=new Set<String>();
Set<String> retrieveAllLinksFromSite (URL url, int Level,Set<String> Links)
{
    if(Level==4)
       return;
    else{

        //retrieveLinksOnPage(url,0);
        //I'm pretty Lost Actually!
        }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: don't use vector. use `Set` and `HashSet`, it will remove duplicated links

Comment: basic principle for recursion is that one of the argument is the same as the returning value.

Comment: typo: "the same" to "the same type"

Comment: @gigadot You can edit your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the pseudo code:

```
Set<String> retrieveAllLinksFromSite(int Level, Set<String> Links) {
    if (Level < 5) {
        Set<String> local_links =  new HashSet<String>();
        for (String link : Links) {
            // do download link
            Set<String> new_links = ;// do parsing the downloaded html of link;
            local_links.addAll(retrieveAllLinksFromSite(Level+1, new_links));
        }
        return local_links;
    } else {
        return Links;
    }

}
```

You will need to implement thing in the comments yourself. To run the function from a given single link, you need to create an initial set of links which contains only one initial link. However, it also works if you ahve multiple initial links.

```
Set<String> initial_link_set = new HashSet();
initial_link_set.add("http://abc.com/");
Set<String> final_link_set = retrieveAllLinksFromSite(1, initial_link_set);
```

Comment: feel free to shout if there is something wrong. it's too late here and my head is getting dizzy.

Comment: Going to try it now, Thanks, Really appreciate it! =)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `HashMap` instead of a `Vector` to store the links and their levels (since you need to recursively get all links down to level 4)

Also , it would be something like this(just giving an overall hint) :

```
HashMap Links=new HashMap();

void retrieveAllLinksFromSite (URL url, int Level)
{
    if(Level==4)
       return;
    else{
        retrieve the links on current page and for each retrieved link,
        do {
           download the link
           Links.put(the retrieved url,Level)  // store the link with level in hashmap
           retrieveAllLinksFromSite (the retrieved url ,Level+1) //recursively call for

 further levels
            }

        }

}
```

Comment: this pseudo code won't help because it doesn't work logically.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I made an error in writing the recursive statement. Can you check again?

Comment: it is still incorrect. a web page may contains multiple links. once you finish downloading every pages under a certain link you want to move on to the next link in the same level. this logic doesn't appear in your pseudo code.